# Exposing the hello-minikube service fails to find a port

Tags: linux, kubernetes, ubuntu-16.04, minikube

I could create the container:

```
$ kubectl run hello-minikube --image=gcr.io/google_containers/echoserver:1.4 --port=
deployment "hello-minikube" created
```

And I'm now trying to expose a service:

```
$ kubectl expose deployment hello-minikube --type=NodePort
error: couldn't find port via --port flag or introspection
```

Even if I delete it, it still comes back of its own:

```
$ kubectl delete pod hello-minikube-2138963058-2szl7
pod "hello-minikube-2138963058-2szl7" deleted
[stephane@stephane-ThinkPad-X201 ~]
$ kubectl get pods
NAME                              READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
hello-minikube-2138963058-nhh1q   1/1       Running   0          3m
```

The is the pod:

```
$ kubectl get pods
NAME                              READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
hello-minikube-2138963058-2szl7   1/1       Running   0          16m
```

And its description:

```
$ kubectl describe pod hello-minikube-2138963058-2szl7
Name:       hello-minikube-2138963058-2szl7
Namespace:  default
Node:       minikube/192.168.42.196
Start Time: Thu, 14 Sep 2017 23:20:03 +0200
Labels:     pod-template-hash=2138963058
        run=hello-minikube
Annotations:    kubernetes.io/created-by={"kind":"SerializedReference","apiVersion":"v1","reference":{"kind":"ReplicaSet","namespace":"default","name":"hello-minikube-2138963058","uid":"2b37ca13-9968-11e7-a720-525400...
Status:     Running
IP:     172.17.0.3
Created By: ReplicaSet/hello-minikube-2138963058
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/hello-minikube-2138963058
Containers:
  hello-minikube:
    Container ID:   docker://5e4ba407d8869e6e843ec3d7876e953147cc01104e980c7febfea218808ab379
    Image:      gcr.io/google_containers/echoserver:1.4
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://gcr.io/google_containers/echoserver@sha256:5d99aa1120524c801bc8c1a7077e8f5ec122ba16b6dda1a5d3826057f67b9bcb
    Port:       <none>
    State:      Running
      Started:      Thu, 14 Sep 2017 23:20:05 +0200
    Ready:      True
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-t8qx7 (ro)
Conditions:
  Type      Status
  Initialized   True 
  Ready     True 
  PodScheduled  True 
Volumes:
  default-token-t8qx7:
    Type:   Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName: default-token-t8qx7
    Optional:   false
QoS Class:  BestEffort
Node-Selectors: <none>
Tolerations:    <none>
Events:
  FirstSeen LastSeen    Count   From            SubObjectPath           Type        Reason          Message
  --------- --------    -----   ----            -------------           --------    ------          -------
  17m       17m     1   default-scheduler                   Normal      Scheduled       Successfully assigned hello-minikube-2138963058-2szl7 to minikube
  17m       17m     1   kubelet, minikube                   Normal      SuccessfulMountVolume   MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "default-token-t8qx7" 
  17m       17m     1   kubelet, minikube   spec.containers{hello-minikube} Normal      Pulled          Container image "gcr.io/google_containers/echoserver:1.4" already present on machine
  17m       17m     1   kubelet, minikube   spec.containers{hello-minikube} Normal      Created         Created container
  17m       17m     1   kubelet, minikube   spec.containers{hello-minikube} Normal      Started         Started container
```

All of this on a host minikube on Linux.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You get this error because you didn't set the container port from the command `kubectl run hello-minikube --image=gcr.io/google_containers/echoserver:1.4 --port=` as such the expose command doesn't know which container port to map to a node port and then error

You have to set exact container port as follow `kubectl run hello-minikube --image=gcr.io/google_containers/echoserver:1.4 --port=80` assuming `80` is the port number and then run the expose again.

See bellow step by step of how I was able to replicate your error and then fix

```
C:\Users\innocent.anigbo\.minikube>kubectl run hello-kube --image=gcr.io/google_
containers/echoserver:1.4 --port=
deployment "hello-kube" created

C:\Users\innocent.anigbo\.minikube>kubectl get pods
NAME                             READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
hello-kube-1448409582-c9sm5      1/1       Running   0          1m
hello-minikube-938614450-417hj   1/1       Running   1          8d
hello-nginx-3322088713-c4rp4     1/1       Running   0          6m

C:\Users\innocent.anigbo\.minikube>kubectl get deployment
NAME             DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
hello-kube       1         1         1            1           2m
hello-minikube   1         1         1            1           8d
hello-nginx      1         1         1            1           7m

C:\Users\innocent.anigbo\.minikube>kubectl get service
NAME          CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
hello-nginx   10.0.0.136   <nodes>       80:32155/TCP   4m
kubernetes    10.0.0.1     <none>        443/TCP        20d

C:\Users\innocent.anigbo\.minikube>kubectl expose deployment hello-kube --type=N
odePort
error: couldn't find port via --port flag or introspection
See 'kubectl expose -h' for help and examples.

C:\Users\innocent.anigbo\.minikube>kubectl delete deployment hello-kube
deployment "hello-kube" deleted

C:\Users\innocent.anigbo\.minikube>kubectl get pods
NAME                             READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
hello-minikube-938614450-417hj   1/1       Running   1          8d
hello-nginx-3322088713-c4rp4     1/1       Running   0          11m

C:\Users\innocent.anigbo\.minikube>kubectl run hello-kube --image=gcr.io/google_
containers/echoserver:1.4 --port=80
deployment "hello-kube" created

C:\Users\innocent.anigbo\.minikube>kubectl get pods
NAME                             READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
hello-kube-2715294448-0rxf2      1/1       Running   0          3s
hello-minikube-938614450-417hj   1/1       Running   1          8d
hello-nginx-3322088713-c4rp4     1/1       Running   0          11m

C:\Users\innocent.anigbo\.minikube>kubectl expose deployment hello-kube --type=N
odePort
service "hello-kube" exposed

C:\Users\innocent.anigbo\.minikube>kubectl get service
NAME          CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
hello-kube    10.0.0.137   <nodes>       80:30004/TCP   3s
hello-nginx   10.0.0.136   <nodes>       80:32155/TCP   9m
kubernetes    10.0.0.1     <none>        443/TCP        20d
```

Comment: I could expose the service `kubectl run hello-minikube --image=gcr.io/google_containers/echoserver:1.4 --port=82` and `kubectl expose deployment hello-minikube --type=NodePort` which shows the service `$ kubectl get services
NAME             CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
hello-minikube   10.0.0.81    <nodes>       82:32515/TCP   4h` but trying to connect fails `$ curl $(minikube service hello-minikube --url)
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.42.196 port 32515: Connection refused`

Comment: But if instead of using the port 82 I use the port 8080 it then works. I thought I could choose my own port here. It's not the case ?

Comment: No you can't use your own port or any random port for that matter. This must be the port the container listens on for traffic as is in the image `echoserver:1.4`.  You will get this port number from the repo where the image is documented. 8080 only works because you were lucky to have guessed the right port. Next time it better you just check this from the image documentation to make it easier for you.

Answer (score 2):

Your pod is reappearing because deployment creates a replica set for the container which creates a new one if the current pod terminates.

Run this to check if there is a replica set deployed.

```
kubectl get rs
```

You should ideally delete the entire deployment

```
kubectl delete deployment <name>
```

Comment: As a k8s noob I didn't know enough about environment and pod to delete the correct one. Your answer plus the one above of Innocent Anigbo solved my issue.